# Wkhtmltopdf - Aws Lambda timed out

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

Getting timed out error while generating PDF's using wkhtmltopdf on AWS Lambda.
Its working fine with some files but when there are large size images that time getting timed out error. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: A lambda function cannot exceed 900 seconds.  If it needs to take longer your lambda should spin up a fargate task and the fargate task should do the work

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently. You need to change the timeout on lambda. Please follow the below steps -

```
Step 1 open Lambda Page
Step 2 Search for your lambda
Step 3 Select Configuration Tab and then select General Configuration
Configuration
Step 4 Change the timeout values as per your requirement
```

Added image for the reference. It should work
[image]